# Почему выводится none?

Tags: python

Код:

```
def selection_sort(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):

        lowest_value_index = i

        for j in range(i + 1, len(A)):
            if A[j] < A[lowest_value_index]:
                lowest_value_index = j

        A[i], A[lowest_value_index] = A[lowest_value_index], A[i]

f = open("input.txt", "r")

line = f.readline()
theList = []
while line:
    theList.append(int(line))
    line = f.readline()
f = open("output.txt", 'w')
f.close()
print(theList)
print(selection_sort(theList))
```

Выводит:

> [2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5, 34, 5, 6, 45, 7457, 54, 74, 56, 456,
>   45, 745, 7, 34, 56, 54, 7, 5687, 54, 67, 5, 8754, 6754, 67, 5]
>
> None

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция `selection_sort` не имеет инструкции `return`, поэтому она возвращает `None`. В python все функции, которые не имеют `return`, либо имеют `return` без аргументов ведут себя так. В [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) указано:

> Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a
>   function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any
>   return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no
>   value is returned should explicitly state this as return None, and an
>   explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function
>   (if reachable):